# Find $A$ such that $ABA = b A$, for every $B \in \mathbb {M}_n \ (\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, contest-math, determinant, matrix-equations

I have met this problem while preparing for the olympiad and I can't crack it:

Find the matrices $A \in \mathbb{M}_n \  (\mathbb {C})$ such that there exists a $b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $ABA = bA$ for every $B \in \mathbb{M}_n \ (\mathbb{C})$.

Of course, $O_n$ is a solution with $b = 0$. I applied the determinant: $\det^2 (A) \ \det (B) = b^n \det (A)$. Since $b$ is fixed and $B$ is a  variable, the only possible way is for $\det (A) = 0$.

Now, for $B = I_n$, $A^2 = bA$ and using induction it is clear that $A^n = b^{n-1}A$. This is all I could get. Can you please help me? But please, try not to use very advanced stuff, as  this problem should be solvable during a contest. With that said, every solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $2B$ for $B$. You get $2(ABA)=2bA=bA$. So $bA=0$. Hence either $b=0$, so $A=0$ (as you proved), or $A=0$. Thus $A=0$ in all cases.

A more interesting problem would be if you allow $b$ depend on $B$.

Comment: I think that would make the problem quite harder, but thank you very much for the very elegant solution!

Comment: I don't see why $b=0$ implies $A=0$. I only see that $A^2=0$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger You are given that $ABA=0$ for every $B$, not just $B=I$.

Comment: Which matrices $B$ will allow to derive $A=0$?

Comment: $E_{i,j}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger If $b = 0$, $A^k = O$ for every natural $k$. So, $ABA + A^2 = O$, $A(BA + A) = O$. Either $A = O$, or $BA + A = O$, which means $(B+I_n)A = O$, for every $B \in \mathbb{M}_n (\mathbb {C})$, so, again $A = O$. I did it because I don't know what $E_{i, j}$ is.

Comment: @andueu: That is not true. $A(BA+A)=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $BA+A=0$. The ring of matrices has zero divisors

Comment: If $AE_{i,j}A=0$ then $A_{j,i}=0$. If that happens for every $i,j$ then $A=0$.